# Logic: "XOR" or "OR"

Tags: logic

The statement: Either ~p or it is the case that $(q\land r)$.

This seems to me to indicate: $\lnot p\lor(q\land r)$. Am I correct?

How would you in words describe the XOR relationship?

And is this the correct representation of the XOR relationship?: $$ \lnot [\lnot p\land (q\land r)]\land [\lnot p\lor (q\land r))]$$

Comment: Propositional logic usually uses "OR": $\lor$.

Comment: [Exclusive disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Equivalences,_elimination,_and_introduction) can obviously defined in terms of other connectives.

Comment: Yes, it's a correct representation for the XOR version.

Comment: *How would you in words describe the XOR relationship?* Is "either but not both" acceptable?

Comment: @ryang Yes. I guess it was a very open question. I think I foresaw some complicated syntax that I'd have to interpret. But I guess it doesn't need to be complicated. Thank you.

Comment: I would say @ryang's comment to this is the answer. Quick and simple.